# CodeIgniter: Understanding routes

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I have the this route defined in **routes.php**
`$route['user'] = "user_controller";`. The user controller has a method `logout()` but when I try this URI `user/logout` I get a 404. In the same way when I use this URI `user/index` I get a 404.

**routes.php**

```
// custom routes
$route['start'] = "start_controller";
$route['register'] = "register_controller";
$route['user'] = "user_controller";

// other routes
$route['default_controller'] = "start_controller";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**According to CI**

> Note: Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes
>   will always take precedence over lower ones.

`$route['default_controller']` and `$route['404_override']` must always be on top above others

```
$route['user/logout'] = "user_controller/logout";
$route['user/index'] = "user_controller";
```

Example i will type a `user/logout` then it will proceed to `user_controller/logout` you have to define the `URL` you would like to redirect

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you have to specify a route for each particular method.

Here's an example from my routes.php :

```
/* User Authentication Controller */
$route['login']     = "auth/login";
$route['logout']    = "auth/logout";
$route['register']  = "auth/register";
$route['forgot']    = "auth/forgot";
```